# Safari issue with HttpContext.User.Identity

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I try to play mp3 file, which is returned by MyAudio method from ContentController, through html5 audio tag. Following code:

```
[Authorize]
    public class ContentController : Controller
    {

        private ContentServices Content { get; set; }

        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.isAuthenticated) 
            {
                base.Initialize(requestContext);
            }

        }


    public ActionResult MyAudio(string name)
    {
        var file = Server.MapPath("~/" + name);
        return File(file, "audio/mp3");
    }
```

Common html code

When the user is Authorized all works perfect in Chrome. But when I have tested it in Safari there is a strange mystery. The HttpContext.User.Identity.isAuthenticated returns false and of course code doesn't execute further.

The interesting thing is that when I use for example @Html.Action or @Html.RouteLink, HttpContext.User.Identity.isAuthenticated will return true.

I've tried to use javascript and jquery to solve the problem, but I also had wierd things at Safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getAudio() {
            if (audio.src == "" || audio.src == null) {
                // (1) audio.src = '@Url.Content("~/Content/MyAudio")' + "hello.mp3";
                // (2) audio.src = '@Url.Action("MyAudio", "Content", new { name = "hello.mp3" } )';
                /* (3) $.get('@Url.Content("~/Content/MyAudio")', {"name": "hello.mp3"}, 
                function(data) {
                alert("hello");
                });
                */
                audio.load();
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Both (1) and (2) have the same problem. But when I use (3), HttpContext.User.Identity.isAuthenticated returns true at Safary. But I guess u can't give file stream through jquery.

Have anyone have an idea what's is go on nad how I can fix the problem?

PS I use ASP.NET Development Server and Safari 5.1.7 Win32 7.

Comment: For reference, which version(s) of Safari are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safary 5.1.7 Win32 7

Comment: You will understand the cause of the issue from here https://discussions.apple.com/message/18076941#18076941